# Correct way to use service manager in Zend3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I was reading Zend 3 documentation on Service Manager and i got this problem.

In documentation it says that if we have some DI in our controller we should update `module.config.php` file and add controllers key and invoke controller not with `InvokableFactory::class` but with custom factory class and add another key service_manager that contains array of classes that my first controller uses.

Ok so i do that:

module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\Controller2::class => Factory\Controller2Factory::class,
            Controller\Controller3::class => Factory\Controller3Factory::class,
        ],
    ],
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\Controller1::class => Factory\Controller1Factory::class
        ],
    ]
```

Controller1Factory.php

```
class Controller1Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new Controller1(
            $container->get(Controller2::class),
            $container->get(Controller3::class),
        );
    }
}
```

But now i have error that Controller2 and Controller3 also have DI in their constuctors, so i make new custom factories and so on and so on...until i get to my models.

And Models also have Dependency that is injected in their controller which is zend native `\Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface` and i now have to edit my conf file again and add `TableGatewayInterface`.

And that is wrong. I should never be forced to inject native zend classes and services this way.

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. You say your models _require_ other classes to be injected into their constructors, yet you don't want to be forced to inject classes using the service manager. (If so, what method would you prefer?)

Comment: @TimFountain Well my model is requiring \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface instance and i am injecting it into the constructor of my model. But as this is zend interface i am not sure that inserting new value in service manager for that particular interface is good.

Comment: You should not be injecting controllers into controllers. Create a separate factory class for every controller that has model dependencies, and inject the model(s) that each needs.

Comment: I re-read your post, and while I can tell you that you should not be doing that, I am trying to understand what you actually want to accomplish. Can you clarify your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Controller has no dependency, it's the best way to declare it in `module.config.php` as you did.

But if it has dependecies, it's better to do it in `Module.php`. You first declare your services, then the controller (don't forget to remove it from `module.config.php`), injecting in it the services it depends :

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Model\MyObjectTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\MyObjectTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\MyObjectTable($tableGateway);
            },
            Model\MyObjectTableGateway::class => function($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\User());
                return new TableGateway('myObject', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ]
    ];
}

public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\MyObjectController::class => function($container) {
                return new Controller\MyObjectController(
                    $container->get(Model\MyObjectTable::class)
                );
            },
        ]
    ];
}
```

And in your controller:

```
private $table;

public function __construct(MyObjectTable $table)
{
    $this->table = $table ;
}
```

It is described in [This ZF3 tutorial page and following](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#back-to-the-controller).

Comment: Using a closure for a factory is not a good idea. It can't be opcode cached, and the merged config array can't be cached. For a production use, you should always make concrete factories, and then reference that in your module config factories section.

Comment: @dualmon This is the way Zend implements it in the "Album" tutoriel. But in the "in depth" tutoriel, they do as you says. I'm learning ZF3 too, and your comment give me the idea to rewrite my application with concrete factories. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe also update your answer once you work that out? Then I could upvote it.